# Как сделать вывод кастомных данных с БД в админке?

Tags: wordpress

Стоит задача сделать отдельный раздел в админке WordPress:
Офисы -> список офисов -> станица редактирования/подробная информация об офисе

Вывод офисов хотелось бы сделать в стандартном стиле WP (http://tiny.cc/hu0t5y), но с некоторыми изменениями.

И для каждого офиса сделать отдельно страницу редактирования и страницу со статистикой.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это лучше всего реализовать и в каком направлении смотреть?

Спасибо!

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я такое делаю используя Custom Post Type и мета-поля. Помогают мне в этом два плагина:

- CPTUI (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). Добавляет в панель управления простой интерфейс для создания и редактирования пользовательских типов записей.
- Advanced Custom Fields (https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). Позволяет использовать различные пользовательские поля для записей и других сущностей. В том числе, есть поле с точкой на карте Google Maps, что бывает полезно для типа записи «Офис».

Вот так выглядит в панели готовый интерфейс для контент-менеджера:

[image: Пример интерфейса]